# Revisions to the "users/recent" tab

Tags: feature-request

Why are questions that I've answered and received upvotes for that are beyond my daily reputation cap no longer being shown in the my "users/recent/reputation" tab?

I miss that feature. Please bring it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Jon Skeet's reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/stackoverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx). As a bonus, it collects results for all *four* trilogy sites.

To answer your question, the SO reptutation tracker still works for me, that is, it shows votes that happen past the 200 daily cap. You may have to click on "Today" and "Reputation" to see everything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Excellent resource